# Ampere's law for a curved wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

Deriving Ampere's law in magnetostatics for an infinitely long straight wire is pretty straightforward. However is it possible to derive it for any curved wire or that can only be shown to work experimentaly? $$\oint_c \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=\mu_0I$$

Comment: *Deriving Ampere's law in magnetostatics for an infinitely long straight wire is pretty straightforward.*  How is this done?

Comment: In magnetostatics, Ampere's law follows from the Biot-Savart law, if that's what you are asking. Wikipedia has [a proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law#The_Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law,_Amp%C3%A8re's_circuital_law,_and_Gauss's_law_for_magnetism). The Biot-Savart law is more "complete" in the sense that it embodies both Ampere's and Gauss' laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the Maxwell's equations as experimental evidence than yes and it's also straight forward.

Take the fourth Maxwell's equation and suppose you have a static electric field $\partial E / \partial t = 0$.
$$
\vec\nabla \times \vec B = \mu_0 \vec j + \mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \mu_0 \vec j
$$
Than integrate both sides of the equation over a surface $\Sigma$ whose border is the closed curve $c$ you are considering.
$$
\iint_\Sigma \vec\nabla \times \vec B\cdot \textrm{d}\vec\Sigma = 
\mu_0\iint_\Sigma \vec \jmath\cdot \textrm{d}\vec\Sigma
$$
Since $\vec j$ is the current density, the integral of $\vec j= \rho\vec v$ is just the net flux of charge over time through $\Sigma$, aka the current through $\Sigma$. So the right-hand side is just $\mu_0 I_\textrm{enc}$. On the left-hand side you can apply the [Stockes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), see also [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Maxwell%27s_equations).
$$
\oint_c \vec B \cdot \textrm{d}\vec l = \mu_0 I_\textrm{enc}
$$
An intuitive proof of the Stockes' theorem relies on the idea that the rotor can be seen as the circulation of the field around an infinitesimal piece of surface and the integral as the sum of all this little contributions.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of magneto-statics (a.k.a. when all currents are steady-state) Ampere's Law holds for **wires of any shape**. No matter what path the current is taking, the loop integral $\oint_c \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}$ is always equal to $\mu_0I_{enc}$, where $I_{enc}$ is the total current enclosed within the path taken by your integral.

However, my guess is that you are curious about solutions of Ampere's law when solving for $\vec{B}$.

In the case of an infinitely long wire, we can use an argument based on symmetry as well as the right-hand-rule to postulate that the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is a constant when a distance $r$ from the infinite wire. Additionally, we can postulate that the direction of this magnetic field follows a circular path around the wire, meaning that our path integral becomes $$\oint_c \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=|\vec{B}(r)|  L_c(r) = B(r) 2\pi r = \mu_0I_{enc}$$

Solving for B, we get that $\vec{B}(r) = \frac{\mu_0I_{enc}}{2\pi r}$.

There are other solutions you can derive from similar situations where you can make simplifying assumptions based on the symmetry of the current-carrying wire. There is also a general solution called the Biot–Savart law, where for a wire following the path $c$ the magnetic field is $$B(x) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_c J(x') \times \frac{(x-x')}{|x-x'|^3}dx'$$.

Comment: Well that wasnt exactly my question. I am aware of a method to derive this law using the already known field of a straight infinite wire. What I was asking is, yes we know that it works for not only straight wires but any types of wires, so how is that property derived or proven?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Like all physical "laws", it is merely a particularly effective generalization of observed behaviors. I don't believe that historically there was a similar derivation for an arbitrary shape of wire like there was for a straight wire, the law was simply seen to hold in a variety of situations, and therefore was assumed to be a general statement about the nature of magnetic fields.

Answer (score 1):

It is an experimental result. Historically, the experiments involve measurements of forces between conductor wires, and Ampère himself was one of the leading researches.

Later on, the notion that this force is mediated by a magnetic field generated by the currents was accepted everywhere. The Biot-Savart law is the key to get the magnetic field of any wire geometry. But few of the situations have analytical solution.

[Here](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf), you can find a review of the issue.